# Really simple live convertion to on fails. Dynamic content

Tags: jquery, events

This is a really easy one, but I can't get it to work. I have the following (old) function that deals with clicks on my carousel:

```
$('#cycleDiv img').live('click', function () {
    alert('hh');
});
```

Since `.live` is a badbad thing, I'd like to convert this simple function to `.on`, but by replacing live, nothing happens. I've also tried:

```
$('#cycleDiv').on('click', 'img', function () {
        alert('hh');
});
```

But nothing happens. I've looked at the documentation, but I can't figure this out.

Also, the images are loaded with ajax, so this is dealing with dynamic content. I know `.on` works on the static elements on my site.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DIV is being added via AJAX as well, you'll need to delegate the handler to the document.  See if this works:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cycleDiv img', function () {
        alert('hh');
});
```